# Executing Multiple SQL statements in a single command against SQLServer Database in vb6

Tags: sql-server, vb6, adodb

I am trying to execute multiple SQL statements against a SQL server database using ADODB and vb6.

when I open a recordset the code stops with the following error code:

Run-time error '3704':
Operation is not allowed when object is closed.

here is my code:

```
Dim sql As String
sql = "WITH " & vbCrLf & _
      "q AS" & vbCrLf & _
      "(SELECT Item_No, Unit_OldQuantity" & vbCrLf & _
      "FROM dbo.The_Units),  sequenced AS" & vbCrLf & _
      "(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Item_No ORDER BY Unit_OldQuantity DESC) AS sequence_id,*" & vbCrLf & _
      "From q)" & vbCrLf & _
      "SELECT Item_No , Unit_OldQuantity" & vbCrLf & _
      "into #tmpTable" & vbCrLf & _
      "From sequenced" & vbCrLf & _
      "Where sequence_id = 1" & vbCrLf & _
      "SELECT sum(The_ItemDetails.Item_Cost / #tmpTable.Unit_OldQuantity * The_ItemDetails.Item_Quantity) AS Total" & vbCrLf & _
      "FROM  The_Items INNER JOIN The_ItemDetails ON The_Items.Item_No = The_ItemDetails.Item_No INNER JOIN #tmpTable ON The_ItemDetails.Item_No = #tmpTable.Item_No" & vbCrLf & _
      "Where the_items.Item_kind = 0"


Dim connText As String
connText = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=AlmohasebSQL;Data Source=server-pc\SQLEXPRESS"
Db_Almohaseb.ConnectionString = connText
Db_Almohaseb.Open
Dim RS_ItemDetails As New ADODB.Recordset
RS_ItemDetails.Open sql, Db_Almohaseb, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
Text1.Text = RS_ItemDetails.RecordCount
```

I can run any other sql statement using the same connection but not this one.
I can also run this command in .net but not in vb6.
Right now I just need to know why this is happening, and I am feeling woozy from banging my head against the desk.
please can someone shed some light on this.

Thanks

Comment: IMO, You don't need those `vbCrLf`s in `sql` variable just use a simple blank space `" "` and this change can be helpfull: `sql = ";WITH " ...` ;).

Comment: Thanks for the input, I actually prefer using vbCrLf just to make sure that I didn't forget any white space in any line; and it improves readability when debugging. All that being said it has nothing to do with the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only available solution to my problem is to move the statements to a stored procedure. 
So I check if the procedure exists in the targeted db, if not I will create the procedure; else, I execute the procedure with the proper parameters.
I have also included the logic for checking the temp file if it exists in the db.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a sql statement with multiple sql statements, you need to use SET NOCOUNT ON, like this:

```
sql = "SET NOCOUNT ON;" & _
      "WITH " & vbCrLf & _
      "q AS" & vbCrLf & _
      "(SELECT Item_No, Unit_OldQuantity" & vbCrLf & _
      "FROM dbo.The_Units),  sequenced AS" & vbCrLf & _
      "(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Item_No ORDER BY Unit_OldQuantity DESC) AS sequence_id,*" & vbCrLf & _
      "From q)" & vbCrLf & _
      "SELECT Item_No , Unit_OldQuantity" & vbCrLf & _
      "into #tmpTable" & vbCrLf & _
      "From sequenced" & vbCrLf & _
      "Where sequence_id = 1" & vbCrLf & _
      "SELECT sum(The_ItemDetails.Item_Cost / #tmpTable.Unit_OldQuantity * The_ItemDetails.Item_Quantity) AS Total" & vbCrLf & _
      "FROM  The_Items INNER JOIN The_ItemDetails ON The_Items.Item_No = The_ItemDetails.Item_No INNER JOIN #tmpTable ON The_ItemDetails.Item_No = #tmpTable.Item_No" & vbCrLf & _
      "Where the_items.Item_kind = 0"
```

Comment: close but no cigar, a new error message after adding the nocount on; option.Run-time error '-2147217887(80040e21) "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done."

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "#" :

```
 #tmpTable.Unit_OldQuantity
```

should be

```
 tmpTable.Unit_OldQuantity
```

Comment: The hash mark is used here to indicate that this is a temporary table. This is not the source of the problem. As I said in my post the same code works fine in Visual Studio 2010; but it won't work in VB6 and ADO2.8.